# Can I enable interrupts on GPIO16 of ESP8266?

Tags: hardware, microcontrollers, wifi, esp8266

Usually, the gpio16 is not used as gpio.

But we can read the state or change the state by writing directly to the registers.

```
WRITE_PERI_REG(PAD_XPD_DCDC_CONF, (READ_PERI_REG(PAD_XPD_DCDC_CONF) & 0xffffffbc) | (uint32)0x1); 
WRITE_PERI_REG(RTC_GPIO_CONF, (READ_PERI_REG(RTC_GPIO_CONF) & (uint32)0xfffffffe) | (uint32)0x0);
WRITE_PERI_REG(RTC_GPIO_ENABLE, READ_PERI_REG(RTC_GPIO_ENABLE) & (uint32)0xfffffffe);
(READ_PERI_REG(RTC_GPIO_IN_DATA) & 1);
```

Is there a way to enable interrupts on this pin by writing directly to the registers?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a fundamental detail question about a particular chip, rather than a question about IoT usage of that chip.

Comment: I think you will get more help on a dedicated forum, rather than on S.E

Comment: Here's a "non-arduino" page that says the same thing http://www.esp8266.com/wiki/doku.php?id=esp8266_gpio_pin_allocations - so, I'm guessing the arduino limitation is due to some lower level limitation

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks. I already solved this issue by using the hardware timer and periodically retrieving the state of the pin.

Comment: I guess the [technical reference](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/esp8266-technical_reference_en_0.pdf) won't help then (there's a16 bit word related to interrupts, with 1 bit per GPIO - so, obviously 1 gpio has to miss out :p)